# Reset a running total if field value is hit

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am able to keep a running total with the below query, and it does that just fine. What I really want, is when the gap field is greater than or equal to the date_diff field, the running total should reset back to the current hrly_qty. I'm sure I could achieve my results with a cursor, but I wanted to know of possible other ways. Ideas?

Example:

[image]

```
WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT a.*, SUM(b.hrly_qty) AS running_total, c.gap 
        FROM #tmpTrxhist2 a
            INNER JOIN #tmpTrxhist2 b ON a.people_id = b.people_id 
                                      AND b.sequence_id <= a.sequence_id
            INNER JOIN incent_level c ON a.owner_division_id = c.owner_division_id
        GROUP BY a.date_diff, a.owner_division_id, a.people_id, a.sequence_id, 
                 a.hrly_qty, c.gap
    )
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY people_id, sequence_id
```

Answer (score -2):

You seldom need a cursor! A simple case statement should suffice. Of the top of my head something like:

```
WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT a.*, SUM(b.hrly_qty) AS running_total, c.gap 
        FROM #tmpTrxhist2 a
            INNER JOIN #tmpTrxhist2 b ON a.people_id = b.people_id 
                                      AND b.sequence_id <= a.sequence_id
            INNER JOIN incent_level c ON a.owner_division_id = c.owner_division_id
        GROUP BY a.date_diff, a.owner_division_id, a.people_id, a.sequence_id, 
                 a.hrly_qty, c.gap
    )
SELECT *,

CASE
     WHEN gap >= date_diff then hrly_qty else gap
END as comp_gap

 FROM CTE
ORDER BY people_id, sequence_id
```

Run the execution plans between the two but SQL is almost always much happier trying to optimise non-cursored code. In my field at least, you usually find cursors are over used and abused by 'proper' C/C++ programmers because they get in their comfort zone when see something that looks a bit like a while-loop rather than think about sets of data. There is a place for cursors, but this isn't it!

Comment: Would one be better than the other? How would I write a case statement for this?